# Add table in word using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word C#

Tags: c#

I have this Word 2010 Office project in VS2010

Can someone point me to the right direction to know how to add a table dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [article from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1702h4a.aspx).

*from the article*

```
object start = 0;
object end = 0;
Word.Range tableLocation = this.Range(ref start, ref end);
this.Tables.Add(tableLocation, 3, 4);
```